# Is that possible to call finish() after some time of application's invisible state?

Tags: android

Is that possible to set a timer which would work on background and triggered on `onStop()`, i.e. when application goes off the user's screen? I need to "kill" the application so it will start from scratch after some time being invisible to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up `Handler.post()`. But note that you might want to provide a reset mechanism of some kind, in case the app is revitalized after `onStop()` but before the kill code works. Otherwise, the kill code will be invoked on a running app.